# Why does Lua's length (#) operator return unexpected values?

Tags: lua

Lua has the # operator to compute the "length" of a table being used as an array.
I checked this operator and I am surprised.

This is code, that I let run under Lua 5.2.3:

```
t = {};
t[0] = 1;
t[1] = 2;
print(#t); -- 1 aha lua counts from one
t[2] = 3;
print(#t); -- 2 tree values, but only two are count
t[4] = 3;
print(#t); -- 4  but 3 is mssing?
t[400] = 400;
t[401] = 401;
print(#t); -- still 4, now I am confused?


t2 = {10, 20, nil, 40}
print(#t2); -- 4 but documentations says this is not a sequence?
```

Can someone explain the rules?

Comment: Explaining the rules is the job of the designers. They have done so in the [documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.6). (Not all documentation is useful for learning but that's where learning should start and continue.)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### About tables in general

*(oh, can't you just give me an array)*

In Lua, a table is the single general-purpose data structure. Table keys can be of any type, like `number`, `string`, `boolean`. Only `nil` keys aren't allowed.

Whether tables can or can't contain `nil` *values* is a surprisingly difficult question which I tried to answer in depth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73445264/1483676). Let's just assume that setting `t[k] = nil` should be the observably the same as never setting `k` at all.

Table construction syntax (like `t2 = {10, 20, nil, 40}`) is a syntactic sugar for creating a table and then setting its values one by one (in this case: `t2 = {}`, `t2[1] = 10`, `t2[2] = 20`, `t2[3] = nil`, `t2[4] = 40`).

### Tables as arrays

*(oh, from this angle it really looks quite arrayish)*

As tables are the only complex data structure in Lua, the language (for convenience) provides some ways for manipulating tables as if they *were* arrays.

Notably, this includes the *length operator* (`#t`) and many standard functions, like `table.insert`, `table.remove`, and more.

The behavior of the length operator (and, in consequence, the mentioned utility functions) is only defined for array-like tables with a particular set of keys, so-called *sequences*.

Quoting the Lua 5.2 Reference manual:

> the length of a table t is only defined if the table is a sequence, that is, the set of its positive numeric keys is equal to {1..n} for some integer n

As a result, the behavior of calling `#t` on a table **not** being a sequence at that time, is **undefined**.

It means that any result could be expected, including `0`, `-1`, or `false`, or an error being raised (unrealistic for the sake of backwards compatibility), or even Lua crashing (quite unrealistic).

Indirectly, this means that the behavior of utility functions that expect a sequence is undefined if called with a non-sequence.

### Sequences and non-sequences

*(it's really not obvious)*

So far, we know that using the length operator on tables not being sequences is a bad idea. That means that we should either do that in programs that are written in a particular way, that guarantees that those tables *will* always be sequences in practice, or, in case we are provided with a table without any assumptions about their content, we should dynamically ensure they are indeed a sequence.

Let's practice. Remember: positive numeric keys have to be in the form {1..n}, e.g. {1}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, etc.

```
t = {}
t[1] = 123
t[2] = "bar"
t[3] = 456
```

**Sequence**. Easy.

```
t = {}
t[1] = 123
t[2] = "bar"
t[3] = 456
t[5] = false
```

**Not a sequence**. {1, 2, 3, 5} is missing 4.

```
t = {}
t[1] = 123
t[2] = "bar"
t[3] = 456
t[4] = nil
t[5] = false
```

**Not a sequence**. `nil` values [aren't considered part of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73445264/1483676), so again we're missing 4.

```
t = {}
t[1] = 123
t[2] = "bar"
t[3.14] = 456
t[4] = nil
t[5] = false
```

**Not a sequence**. `3.14` is positive, but isn't an integer.

```
t = {}
t[0] = "foo"
t[1] = 123
t[2] = "bar"
```

**Sequence**. `0` isn't counted for the length and utility functions will ignore it, but this is a valid sequence. The definition only gives requirements about *positive* number keys.

```
t = {}
t[-1] = "foo"
t[1] = 123
t[2] = "bar"
```

**Sequence**. Similar.

```
t = {}
t[1] = 123
t["bar"] = "foo"
t[2] = "bar"
t[false] = 1
t[3] = 0
```

**Sequence**. We don't care about non-numeric keys.

### Diving into the implementation

*(if you really have to know)*

But [what happens in C implementation of Lua when we call `#` on a non-sequence](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/ltable.c.html#luaH_getn)?

Background: Tables in Lua are internally divided into array part and hash part. That's an optimization. Lua tries to avoid allocating memory often, so it pre allocates for the next power of two. That's another optimization.

1. When the last item in the array part is `nil`, the result of `#` is the length of the shortest valid sequence found by binsearching the array part for the first nil-followed key.
2. When the last item in the array part is not `nil` AND the hash part is empty, the result of `#` is the physical length of the array part.
3. When the last item in the array part is not `nil` AND the hash part is NOT empty, the result of `#` is the length of the shortest valid sequence found by binsearching the hash part  for for the first nil-followed key (that is such positive integer `i` that `t[i] ~= nil` and `t[i+1] == nil`), assuming that the array part is full of non-nils(!).

So the result of `#` is *almost* always the (desired) length of the shortest valid sequence, unless the last element in the array part representing a non-sequence is non-nil. Then, the result is *bigger* than desired.

Why is that? It seems like **yet another optimization** (for power-of-two sized arrays). The complexity of `#` on such tables is `O(1)`, while other variants are `O(log(n))`.

Comment: After a few years I've edited this answer, explaining in more depth what it means for a table to be a sequence in Lua.

Comment: Not sure if this deserves a question in its own right but how does the C `lua_next(t)` i.e. with the second argument a `nil` treat a *non*-sequence array? Does it follow the same sort of undefined (but probably not fatal!) behaviour - it ***seems*** to under Lua 5.1 but I'd like to know for certain!

Comment: @SlySven `lua_next` / `next` don't seem to have any special treatment of sequence tables. It's a general-use operator for traversing tables. The order in which the table (sequence or not) is traversed [is unspecified](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-next).

Comment: The _order_ is unspecified, but the general behavior **is**. So it doesn't seem to be in the same league.

Comment: Ah but if you leave the "current" key at the top of the *stack* doesn't the C `lua_next(...)` function use that as an index to return the "next" key/value pair? If that is not a numeric value from the monotonic (i.e. starting from `1` and incrementing by unity for each successive one) sequence that a "sequence" (*list-type*) table requires then it does come back to the same league!

Comment: I'm not sure where our understanding is different. I'll point out some observations: 1. Lua Reference seems to use the terms "index" and "key" interchangeably 2. `next` and `lua_next` are the same thing, the first is a native Lua interface and the second is the Lua C API interface 3. Quoting the reference for `next`: _The order in which the indices are enumerated is not specified, even for numeric indices._

Comment: @SlySven If that didn't answer your question, you might ask about details [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254927/room-for-discussing-lua-semantics), as comments are not for excessive discussions

Comment: "the behavior of calling #t on a table not being a sequence at that time, is **undefined**. It means that any result could be expected": This answer is a little outdated and is specific to Lua 5.2; it could be improved by referencing later documentation instead of just relying on reading the implementation. For Lua 5.1 and also 5.3 and later, the manual explicitly describes what values could be returned for non-sequences. Lua 5.2 does work the same way as the other versions, it was just left out of the manual for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

In Lua only specially formed tables are considered an array.  They are not really an array such as what one might consider as an array in the C language.  The items are still in a hash table.  But the keys are numeric and contiguous from 1 to N.  Lua arrays are unit offset, not zero offset.
The bottom line is that if you do not know if the table you have formed meets the Lua criteria for an array then you must count up the items in the table to know the length of the table.  That is the only way.  Here is a function to do it:

```
function table_count(T)
  local count = 0
  for _ in pairs(T) do count = count + 1 end
  return count
end
```

If you populate a table with the "insert" function used in the manner of the following example, then you will be guaranteed of making an "array" table.

```
s={}
table.insert(s,[whatever you want to store])
```

table.insert could be in a loop or called from other places in your code.  The point is, if you put items in your table in this way then it will be an array table and you can use the # operator to know how many items are in the table, otherwise you have to count the items.

Answer (score 0):

This iterator *should* get all values from an array:

```lua
function npairs(t)
  local i = 0
  local n = #t
  return function()
    i = i + 1
    if i <= n then return i, t[i] end
  end
end
```

But as said in the top answer:

> the behavior of calling #t on a table not being a sequence at that time, is undefined.

The result is also different in different implementations of Lua, for example,
given:

```
local a = { 1, nil, 2, nil, 3, nil, 4 }
for k, v in npairs(a) do
  print(k, v)
end
```

Lua 5.4.4 prints:

```
1   1
2   nil
3   2
4   nil
5   3
6   nil
7   4
```

While LuaJIT prints:

```
1   1
```

As a result, I don't trust the length operator for this kind of things.

This iterator seems to work in LuaJIT too, although it's surely slower:

```lua
function npairs(t)
  local i, n = 0, 0
  local indices = {}
  for k in pairs(t) do
    if type(k) == "number" and k > n then
      n = k
    end
  end
  return function()
    i = i + 1
    if i <= n then return i, t[i] end
  end
end
```

Test:

```lua
local a = { 1, nil, 2, nil, 3, nil, 4, nil, nil }
for k, v in npairs(a) do
  print(k, v)
end
```

Output:

```
1   1
2   nil
3   2
4   nil
5   3
6   nil
7   4
```

This one would skip indices with a `nil` value:

```lua
function npairs(t)
  local i, n = 0, 0
  local indices = {}
  for k in pairs(t) do
    if type(k) == "number" and k > n then
      n = k
    end
  end
  return function()
    while i < n do
      i = i + 1
      if t[i] ~= nil then
        return i, t[i]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Test:

```lua
local a = { 1, nil, 2, nil, 3, nil, 4, nil, nil }
for k, v in npairs(a) do
  print(k, v)
end
```

Output:

```
1   1
3   2
5   3
7   4
```