# Lua - Size of table returning different

Tags: lua, lua-table

guys. Someone can help me with this?

Input

```
a = {}

a.c = {1,2,3}

print(#a)

print(a.c)
```

Output

```
0

table: 0x11ed7a0
```

Why #a is 0? Why not 1?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Lua's length (#) operator return unexpected values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590885/why-does-luas-length-operator-return-unexpected-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is zero because your table `a` is not a sequence.

A sequence is a table that uses keys from 1..n where n is the size of the sequence.

In other words, `#` is used for sequence length, not table length.

From the [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html)

> A table with exactly one border is called a sequence. For instance, the table 
>       {10, 20, 30, 40, 50} is a sequence, as it has only one border (5). The table 
>       {10, 20, 30, nil, 50} has two borders (3 and 5), and therefore it is not a 
>       sequence. The table {nil, 20, 30, nil, nil, 60, nil} has three borders (0, 3, 
>       and 6), so it is not a sequence, too. The table {} is a sequence with border 0. 
>       Note that non-natural keys do not interfere with whether a table is a sequence.
>
> When t is a sequence, #t returns its only border, which corresponds to the 
>       intuitive notion of the length of the sequence. When t is not a sequence, #t 
>       can return any of its borders. (The exact one depends on details of the 
>       internal representation of the table, which in turn can depend on how the table 
>       was populated and the memory addresses of its non-numeric keys.)

Answer (score 1):

Lua tables are a different kind of construct than those in other languages. As the [Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html) reads:

> Tables are the main (in fact, the only) data structuring mechanism in Lua, and a powerful one. We use tables to represent ordinary arrays, symbol tables, sets, records, queues, and other data structures, in a simple, uniform, and efficient way.

In addition, a table is dynamic enough that you can use it in multiple ways at once. For example, a table could be used both as an array and a map at the same time. This has some unfortunate consequences internally. Internally, each Lua table has two parts: the array and hash map.

The length operator only operates on the array portion of the table; no extra memory is used to store the total number of items in the table including the hash map portion. If that functionality is desired, it must be manually implemented. A couple good ways to do so would be using getters and setters, manually updating a local counter, or using a proxy table with index and newindex metamethods.

As an interresting side note, it can sometimes become difficult to tell if a value is stored in the array or hash portions of the table. Consider these examples in Lua 5.3:

```
1: t = {true, nil, true}  -- #t = 3
2: t = {true, [2] = true} -- #t = 2
3: t = {true, [3] = true} -- #t = 1
4: t = {true, true, true} t[2] = nil -- #t = 3
```

Comment: A minor quibble, though I might be misunderstanding you: the length operator does take into account integer keys in the hash part of the table. For instance, in Lua 5.3 `t = {1, 2, nil, 4} t[5] = 5` creates a 4-entry array part containing the keys `1`, `2`, `4` and one-entry hash part containing the key `5` (I checked with the latest version of [lua-getsize](https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-getsize) from Github), but `#t` is `5` rather than `4`.

Comment: The example you gave, `t = {1, 2, nil, 4}` creates an array internally of size 8 and fills locations 1, 2, and 3 (represented as 0, 1, and 2 internally) with numbers. It then adds a fifth element to it, which also fits into the array. This makes the size of the array 5.

Comment: Another interesting note is that only the array size is stored, not the number of elements in the array. When <a href="https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/ltable.c.html#luaH_getn"> luaH_getn </a> is called, it does a binary search starting at the array end for nils to determine the length, making `t = {true, true, true, true} t[8] = true` return an length of 8. Some interesting other cases due to this binary search are `t = {true, true, true, true} t[6] = true` --> length 6, and `t = {true, true, true, true} t[7] = true` --> length 4. In short, length on sparse arrays is undefined.