# LUA: #table key reference suddenly alters table entries

Tags: lua

```
--tables for the 1st example
local table1EX1={1,2,3}
local table2EX1={4,5}
local temp={}

-- 1st example:
temp=table1EX1
for i=1,2 do
  temp[3+i]=table2EX1[i]
  print("#temp = "..#temp)
end

-- output from the print command:
-- #temp = 4
-- #temp = 5
-- this is what I intended to do but I need it to adapt to a changing table size

--tables for the 2nd example
local table1EX2={1,2,3}
local table2EX2={4,5}
local temp={}

-- 2nd example:
temp=table1EX2
for i=1,#table2EX2 do
  temp[#table1EX2+i]=table2EX2[i]
  print("#temp = "..#temp)
end

-- output from the print command:
-- #temp = 4
-- #temp = 6
-- this is what I tried and where I noticed something is wrong
```

#table_name only ever returns a single value and that's the numeric range from the first to the last entry within the named table.

Tests to confirm this:
#1:

```
local tab={-1,0,_,nil,"a",nil,"x",_,3}
print(#tab) -- returns 9
```

#2:

```
local tab={1,2,3}
print(#tab) -- returns 3
tab[2]=nil
print(#tab) -- returns 3
```

#3:

```
local tab={1,2,3}
print(#tab) -- returns 3
tab[3]=nil
print(#tab) -- returns 2
```

I don't understand what's going wrong and why between example#1 and example#2: The code should work the same: table1EX1 and table1EX2 never receive any changes to their contents or size, because the temp variable is used to store the values in both cases. Yet in example#2 the code suddenly causes a change to the contents of table1, as can be seen by the print command output.

While the entire issue can be avoided by assigned variables, like...

```
--tables for the 2nd example
local table1EX2={1,2,3}
local table2EX2={4,5}
local temp={}

-- 2nd example:
temp=table1EX2
local x,y=#table2EX2,#table1EX2
for i=1,x do
  temp[y+i]=table2EX2[i]
  print("#temp = "..#temp)
end
```

...I'd like to understand what's wrong and why.
Also what's the '#' properly called in English in this case ? Sharp, like in C# ? Lozenge, like the dictionary shows ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Lua's length (#) operator return unexpected values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590885/why-does-luas-length-operator-return-unexpected-values)

Comment: The `#` length operator is not defined for non-sequence tables, it should only be used when you know your table is a sequence otherwise results will be unpredictable. As for what we call `#` in english, it has many names `number sign`, `pound`, `hashtag`. I tend to favor number sign or if specifically lua i would call it length operator.

Comment: The rule for the # operator in Lua is simple, as far as I can tell: it tells the length of a *table that is a sequence* if *it does not have any nil values*. Usage in any other situation is highly discouraged.

Comment: (It does specify as well that, if there is a nil in a sequence, then it may return any number such that the next is nil. Please refrain from having nils in your sequence!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look what you're doing here. See comments

#### Exampe 1

```
local table1EX1={1,2,3} -- create a table with 3 elements
local table2EX1={4,5} -- create another table with 3 elements
local temp={} -- create an empty table

temp=table1EX1 -- temp now refers to table1EX1
-- in a loop append the 2 elements of table2EX1 to table2EX1 (or temp, same table)
for i=1,2 do
  temp[3+i]=table2EX1[i] -- first run temp[3+1], second temp[3+2]
  print("#temp = "..#temp)
end
```

Instead of

```
local temp = {}
temp = table1EX1
```

simply write

```
local temp = table1EX1
```

#### Example 2

```
local table1EX2={1,2,3} -- create a table with 3 elements
local table2EX2={4,5}  -- create a table with 2 elements
local temp={}  -- create an empty table

temp=table1EX2  -- temp now refers to table1EX2
-- in a loop from 1 to #table2EX2 (2)
for i=1,#table2EX2 do
  temp[#table1EX2+i]=table2EX2[i] -- first run temp[3+1], second temp[4+2]
  print("#temp = "..#temp)
end
```

You added 1 element to `temp`, so you added 1 element to `table1EX2` because both refer to the same table. hence in the second loop cycle `#table1EX2` is `4`. That's the difference to example 1.

**table values are copied by reference!** `local temp = table1EX1` does not copy any value from `table1EX1` to `temp`. `temp` is just another reference to the table `table1EX1` refers to.

```
local tab={-1,0,_,nil,"a",nil,"x",_,3}
print(#tab) -- returns 9
```

This is dangerous. Please refer to the Lua manual: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.7

> When t is a sequence, #t returns its only border, which corresponds to
> the intuitive notion of the length of the sequence. When t is not a
> sequence, #t can return any of its borders. (The exact one depends on
> details of the internal representation of the table, which in turn can
> depend on how the table was populated and the memory addresses of its
> non-numeric keys.)

Only use the length operator if you know t is a sequence. That's a Lua table with integer indexes 1,..n without any gap.

> Also what's the '#' properly called in English in this case ? Sharp,
> like in C#

It's the number sign or hash. In case of Lua it's called the *length operator*

Read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign