# Can't remove an item from a table (Lua)

Tags: lua, lua-table

So I've been trying to fix this for more than a hour and still haven't fix this yet. So can I ask a question about this project I'm currently working on that I can't remove an item from a table IDK why but help me fix this please.

table: 13411d36

Code

```
participator = {"Zeroo#7497"}
for i, v in pairs(participator) do
    table.remove(participator, i)
end
```

Output

```
Runtime Error : org.luaj.vm2.LuaError: Zeroo#7497.lua:488: invalid key to 'next'
```

Can somebody please help me why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758991/how-to-remove-a-lua-table-entry-by-its-key

Comment: Simply do `participator[i]=nil`.

Comment: lhf I did that but didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `table.remove()` do a shifting if it not removes the last key/value pair.
( If key 1 is removed key 2 becomes key 1 and so on )
Thats a problem for pairs (next).
Better, faster and safer is to make a countdown and let `table.remove()` delete the last key/value pair what is the default for the remove function.
That dont shifting the table.
Example:

```
participator = {"one", "two", "three"}

for i = #participator, 1, -1 do
    print('Deleting:', i, table.remove(participator))
    print('Size:', #participator)
end
```

That makes...

```
Deleting:   3   three
Size:   2
Deleting:   2   two
Size:   1
Deleting:   1   one
Size:   0
```